# image height inside div container

Tags: css

I have a problem with my image which is inside a div.
This div with swiper__content class gives kind of bottom padding to the image and I can't see what cause this effect. I have a 100% height with no padding or margin so it might fit in the div
[image]

```css
.no-padding{
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}
.swiper {
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Impact";
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__content {
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  
}
.swiper .swiper__content img{
  opacity: 0;
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  

transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
  
}
.swiper__bar, .swiper__bar--right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.swiper__bar--right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.swiper.revealed .swiper__content {
  animation-name: kf-font-reveal;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  color: orange;
}

.swiper.revealed .swiper__content img{
  opacity: 1;


}
```

```html
<div class="swiper no-padding revealed">
<div class="swiper__content">
<img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1">
</div>
<span class="swiper__bar--right"></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `line-height: 0` for your `swiper` class.

```css
.no-padding{
  padding: 0px 0px !important;
}
.swiper {
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 10vw;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Impact";
  cursor: pointer;
}

.swiper__content {
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
  
}
.swiper .swiper__content img{
  opacity: 0;
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  

transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 0s ease-in 0.5s;
  
}
.swiper__bar, .swiper__bar--right {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.swiper__bar--right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.swiper.revealed .swiper__content {
  animation-name: kf-font-reveal;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  color: orange;
}

.swiper.revealed .swiper__content img{
  opacity: 1;


}
```

```html
<div class="swiper no-padding revealed">
<div class="swiper__content">
<img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1">
</div>
<span class="swiper__bar--right"></span>
</div>
```